# jQuery remove class when adding it to other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 6 images in a line, the first one when the page loads has a class applied to it which using CSS3 applies web transformations. When the other images are hovered over the same class is applied to these, then removed when mouseout. The final thing I need to achieve is that when the other images are hovered over the first one has the class removed, and if no images are hovered over the first one has its class applied to it again.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imagePackshot li img").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('packshot').siblings().removeClass('packshot');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('packshot');
    })
    .first().addClass('packshot');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check after you remove a class whether there are no other images with the class 'packshot', in that case add it to the first one.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var activeClass = 'packshot', images = $("#gallerySlideshow li img");
        var first = images.first().addClass(activeClass);
        images.hover(function(){
            // remove the class from all images who still have it, most likely only one.
            images.filter("."+activeClass).removeClass(activeClass); 
            // add class to the element that was hovered.
            $(this).addClass(activeClass);
        },
        function () {
            // remove class from the image that was hovered out of
            $(this).removeClass(activeClass);
            // if no other images have the active class, then give it to the first image
            if(!images.filter("."+activeClass).size()){
               first.addClass(activeClass);
            }
        })
  });
```

Edit:

The code is using this html structure, based on the link you posted, which means you can't use "siblings" to refer to the next images, since the images aren't siblings in the html tree:

```
<ul id="gallerySlideshow">
    <li>
        <a href="page9.html"><img src="thumbnails/thumb9.jpg" width="158" height="236" /></a>
        <ul id="noimg">
            <li>
                <a href=""><img src="Images/more-like-this.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="page9.html"><img class="box2" src="thumbnails/thumb1.jpg" /></a>
        <ul id="noimg">
            <li>
                <a href=""><img src="Images/more-like-this.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="page9.html"><img class="box" src="thumbnails/thumb3.jpg"  /></a>
        <ul id="noimg">
            <li>
                <a href=""><img src="Images/more-like-this.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>



    <li>
        <a href="page9.html"><img class="box1" src="thumbnails/thumb4.jpg" /></a>
        <ul id="noimg">
            <li>
                <a href=""><img src="Images/more-like-this.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="page9.html"><img class="box3" src="thumbnails/thumb5.jpg" /></a>
        <ul id="noimg">
            <li>
                <a href=""><img src="Images/more-like-this.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="page9.html"><img class="box4" src="thumbnails/thumb6.jpg" /></a>
        <ul id="noimg">
            <li>
                <a href=""><img src="Images/more-like-this.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi ggreiner, thanks for helping out, although it is still not working how I need it, as previous, I need on page load the first image to be highlighted and enlarged (addClass) then on hover of rest they are highlighted and enlarged and the first one is reduced and highlight off, if no images are hovered over the first one goes back to being highlighted and enlarged, see the webpage for example of how it is at the moment.  

[link]http://geoffboult.co.uk/clients/jq/page5.3.html

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect the html structure in your example

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, its now how I need it. I tried to find how to send you a PM to say thanks and maybe see if I could send you a thanks donation towards some beers next time your on the town. Thanks again...

Comment: That works great, I do have one other thing I need to try and accomplish, the images need to have 2 lines of text associated with each, this text needs to be displayed in a fixed 'same possition' in the centre of all the images (not like a tooltip where it displays next to each image) and on page load the first images description text is show, just like the first image is highlighted then on hover over of the others the text description changes to that of the hovered over image) would you like to take this on as a paid project for me?